# Can i concat the last insert id in the first insert?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use the PRIMARY id on the INSERT or do i need to make one INSERT first and one SELECT LAST INSERT ID() and then another INSERT with CONCAT?

What i want is to create a column with two combined cells.

Let's say i have two columns: id & string
When i make a INSERT i'd like to combine this two in the string column.

```
id.    string
---------------
1.     string_1
2.     string_2
53.    string_53
```

QUERY:

```
INSERT INTO table SET string = 'string_';
SELECT LAST INSERT ID();
UPDATE table SET string = CONCAT(string, last insert id) WHERE id = last insert id;
```

Do i need to make this three calls, or can i make it in one single row query?
How should my query look like?

Comment: *can i make it in one single row query?* No.

Comment: Why would you want to store easily derivable information?

Comment: @Strawberry because "string" is uniqe and in some special cases the strings is duplicates but need to be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two queries is enough:

```
INSERT INTO table 
    SET string = 'string_';
UPDATE table 
    SET string = CONCAT(string, id) WHERE string = 'string_';
```

Comment: ah, smart! Thank you!